# How can I secure the views in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app with external jwt authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and I'm working on a small project where users can:

1. Sign In (form is sent to an external API which returns a JWT token)
2. View pages but only after authentication. The pages are data driven which will be fetched from external API using the JWT token.

I have tried to find answers but have not been able to get a clear answer. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you will need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package
2. In the `Program.cs`file (Depending if you want to use a Startup.cs or just go with the Program.cs as per default) you should Add the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` and the `DefaultChallengeScheme`  :

**The examples are without Startup.cs just for default Programm.cs from now on**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

// Some Code

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }) 
// Some Code
```

3. then you need to configure the JWT Bearer token so chain the `AddJwtBearer` to the previous example and add authorizationwith `AddAuthorization`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }) // End of last snippet
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

3. Then you should  specify the `Authentication` and `Authorization` Middleware by using :

```
// Program.cs
// after the old code snippet
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication(); //Add this
app.UseAuthorization(); //Add this

app.Run();
```

If you want to use `Minimal API` the full example could look like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCapDashboardStandalone();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapGet("/",  () => Results.LocalRedirect("/index.html", true));

app.MapPost("/security/createToken",
    [AllowAnonymous](User user) =>
    {
        if (user is { UserName: "bob", Password: "bob" })
        {
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim("Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,
                        Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
                Issuer = "Test",
                Audience = "Test",
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials
                (new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return Results.Ok(stringToken);
        }
        return Results.Unauthorized();
    });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a head start and your examples gave me just that.